# Как поместить выбранное изображение в Div по изменению значения option класса Select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, img

```html
<form class="form_calc_delivery" action="script.jsx">
  <p>
    Калькулятор Грузоперевозок
  </p>
  <div id="change_img_car">
  </div>
  <select class="list_car">
    <option class="optGazel">Gazel NEXT</option>
    <option class="optMercedes">Mercedes Sprinter</option>
    <option class="optFord">Ford Transit</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под "поместить в div"? какие option есть?

Comment: let imgGazel = document.querySelector("optGazel");
let imgMercedes = document.querySelector("optMercedes");
let imgFord = document.querySelector("optFord");
if (imgGazel) {
  document.change_img_car.innerhtml = '';
}
попытался через js, но не могу понять как выбрать чтобы загрузить изображение в div change_img_car, смотря какой option выбирает пользователь

Comment: @handowl  попытался через js, но не могу понять как выбрать чтобы загрузить изображение в div change_img_car, смотря какой option выбирает пользователь. Код сверху. Нашел как добавить в div текст + .thisValue т.е Gazel next и т.д а хочу картинку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Описание работы кода в комментариях к нему.

```js
let selCar = document.querySelector('.list_car'), // Берём селектор
    viewCar = document.querySelector('#change_img_car'); // и берём блок в котором находятся картинки авто

// Проверяем какой option выбран, изначально будет первый, его и отобразим
viewCar.querySelector(`[alt="${selCar.value}"]`).classList.add('--show');

// Вешаем обработчик на изменение `option`
selCar.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  viewCar.querySelector('.--show').classList.remove('--show'); // Удаляем класс с выбранной ранее картинки
  viewCar.querySelector(`[alt="${e.target.value}"]`).classList.add('--show'); // И вешаем новый, который есть у выбранного option
});
```

```css
#change_img_car {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Весь "фокус" завязан на том, что изначально все картинки скрыты и отобразятся только когда у них будет класс --show */

#change_img_car img {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: 0;
}

#change_img_car img.--show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Калькулятор Грузоперевозок</p>
<!--
  alt картинок должен совпадать с value в селекторе, чтобы картинки выводились нужные.
-->
<div id="change_img_car">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/8616zk3.png" alt="Gazel NEXT">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/8GbFMHo.png" alt="Mercedes Sprinter">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/QJUCByF.png" alt="Ford Transit">
</div>
<select class="list_car">
  <option value="Gazel NEXT">Gazel NEXT</option>
  <option value="Mercedes Sprinter">Mercedes Sprinter</option>
  <option value="Ford Transit">Ford Transit</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо, знак Хэш # в начале класса ставится? И все переменные и названия классов надо в стиле camelCase ставить что в HTML, JS, CSS? Часик потрачу, разберус.

Comment: `#` - это `id`, он у вас указан. Названия переменных, классов можете писать как вам удобно, но только не запутайтесь.